# vbs open the website by adding 1 number in every link

Tags: vbscript

Can someone help me to complete my code
like this:

```
set w = WScript.CreateObject ("wscript.shell")
w.run "chrome.exe"
WScript.Sleep (3000)
w.SendKeys "www.websitename.com/profile/1"
w.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WScript.Sleep (6000)
w.SendKeys "{F6}"
w.SendKeys "www.websitename.com/profile/2"
w.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

open the website and continue until 100 or more

but I have to use a lot of code for this script, it is very difficult
Can you help me to simplify it?
like "www.websitename.com/profile/2" adding 1 number every link
thank you

Comment: Can you clarify why you are doing this?

Comment: you want to use a counter and a for next loop to add the counter to the url and run it. but there are other issues with your logic, you can just run the url instead of chrome, if chrome is your default browser, that way you don't need to mess with sendkeys. Even if you want to run chrome.exe you should do it as a process and you can set the url as an argument to the executable in the process.

Answer (score 0):

you would use this code to generate the urls and then open them through your default browser!

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim web As String
    For value As Integer = 1 To 100

        web = "www.websitename.com/profile/" & value
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(web)

    Next

End Sub
```

This code works opened a whole load of pages for me